# Capture the output of __repr__ function in a variable

Tags: python

I have the below code base:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Person:
    def __init__(self,day,month,year):
        self.day = day
        self.mon = month
        self.year = year
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.day < 10:
            day = "0" + str(self.day)
        else:
            day = str(self.day)
        if self.mon < 10:
            mon = "0" + str(self.mon)
        else:
            mon = str(self.mon)
        display = day + "-" + mon + "-" + str(self.year)
        return display

def sortdates(l1):
    for dates in l1:
        date.finalbirthdate = datetime.strptime(str(print(dates)),"%d-%m-%Y")
        print (date.finalbirthdate)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Person(18,9,1984)
    print (p1)
    p2 = Person(13,1,1988)
    print (p2)
    sortdates([p1,p2])
```

Now the main function of sortdates function is to sort the Person objects as per the dates. For that i somehow need to convert the string representation of the Person object into datetime object.

Also since i have to do that i have to somehow capture the string representation into a variable and pass that to datetime.strptime function.

Can someone please guide me out on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use `__str__` instead...? And you could use the repl() function

Comment: `repr(dates)` would do it - remove `str(print(...))`

Comment: Not sure why `datetime` was changed to `DateTime`... python only has `datetime` which you can import in the standard library.

Comment: I can use that , but the main issue still remains. How to capture the output of __str__ in a variable to pass to datetime.strptime function?

Comment: Yes s = repr(p1) seems to be working ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to define `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__eq__` methods for your `Person` object; this way your Person object becomes "sortable" on its own.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,day,month,year):
        self.day = day
        self.mon = month
        self.year = year

    def _as_date(self):
        return datetime.date(self.year, self.mon, self.day)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._as_date() < other._as_date()

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._as_date() > other._as_date()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._as_date() == other._as_date()

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return ! self.__eq__(other)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}-{}-{}'.format(str(self.day).zfill(2),
                                 str(self.mon).zfill(2),
                                 self.year)
```

Now, you can just sort your objects directly:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Person(18,9,1984)
    print (p1)
    p2 = Person(13,1,1988)
    print (p2)
    sorted_dates = sorted([p1,p2])
```